# Is there is any way to get honeypot log files

Tags: honeypot, intrusion-detection

I am developing project. Which is related to honey pots.My problem is there any way to get open source honey pot log files.If it possible, Please provide a link or give any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

That would be very easy to do. Here's a PHP example:

```
if($_POST[shouldBeEmpty] == "") {
  // the field is empty, so deal with the form submission
}
else {
  // you are dealing with a spammer, therefore add to the log file
}
```

Of course, don't name your field "shouldBeEmpty". Name it something normal-sounding such as "contactNumber" or "message".